# Assign (add) a new column to a dask dataframe based on values of 2 existing columns - involves a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I would like to add a new column to an existing dask dataframe based on the values of the 2 existing columns and involves a conditional statement for checking nulls:

**DataFrame definition**

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [0.2, "", 0.345, 0.40, 0.15]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=2)
```

**Method-1 tried**

```
def funcUpdate(row):
    if row['y'].isnull():
        return row['y']
    else:
        return  round((1 + row['x'])/(1+ 1/row['y']),4)

ddf = ddf.assign(z= ddf.apply(funcUpdate, axis=1 , meta = ddf))
```

It gives an error:

```
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type DataFrame
```

**Method-2**

```
ddf = ddf.assign(z = ddf.apply(lambda col: col.y if col.y.isnull() else  round((1 + col.x)/(1+ 1/col.y),4),axis = 1, meta = ddf))
```

Any idea how it should be done ?

Comment: use `numpy.where`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either use `fillna` (fast) or you can use `apply` (slow but flexible)

#### Fillna

```
import pandas as pd

import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [0.2, None, 0.345, 0.40, 0.15]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf['z'] = ddf.y.fillna((100 + ddf.x))

>>> df

   x      y
0  1  0.200
1  2    NaN
2  3  0.345
3  4  0.400
4  5  0.150

>>> ddf.compute()

   x      y        z
0  1  0.200    0.200
1  2    NaN  102.000
2  3  0.345    0.345
3  4  0.400    0.400
4  5  0.150    0.150
```

Of course in this case though because your function uses `y` if `y` is a null, the result will be null as well.  I'm assuming that you didn't intend this, so I changed the output slightly.

#### Use apply

As any Pandas expert will tell you, using `apply` comes with a 10x to 100x slowdown penalty.  Please beware.

That being said, the flexibility is useful.  Your example almost works, except that you are providing improper metadata.  You are telling apply that the function produces a dataframe, when in fact I think that your function was intended to produce a series.  You can have Dask guess the meta information for you (although it will complain) or you can specify the dtype explicitly.  Both options are shown in the example below:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: import dask.dataframe as dd
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [0.2, None, 0.345, 0.40, 0.15]})
   ...: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
   ...: 

In [2]: def func(row):
   ...:     if pd.isnull(row['y']):
   ...:         return row['x'] + 100
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return row['y']
   ...:     

In [3]: ddf['z'] = ddf.apply(func, axis=1)
/home/mrocklin/Software/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:2553: UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result
  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result
  warnings.warn(msg)

In [4]: ddf.compute()
Out[4]: 
   x      y        z
0  1  0.200    0.200
1  2    NaN  102.000
2  3  0.345    0.345
3  4  0.400    0.400
4  5  0.150    0.150

In [5]: ddf['z'] = ddf.apply(func, axis=1, meta=float)

In [6]: ddf.compute()
Out[6]: 
   x      y        z
0  1  0.200    0.200
1  2    NaN  102.000
2  3  0.345    0.345
3  4  0.400    0.400
4  5  0.150    0.150
```

Comment: you are right I didn't the y to be null. Actually i was defining the Null value incorrectly and that was causing the error too.  Thanks for your explaination, helped a lot.  Although i am not sure the fastna will help or not because  the actual function is like this:  `def func(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['y']):
        return row['x']
    else:
        return  round((1 + row['x'])/(1 + 1/row['y']),4)`  Basically if y is null, the new column z = x , otherwise the new column z is equal to that calculation in the return statement.

Comment: Another question is why can't isnull be applied to a column of a dask dataframe , using the pandas syntax was kind of surprising to me: `if pd.isnull(row['y']):`

Comment: how can I apply .assign in this case ?

Comment: I use `pd.isnull(row['y'])` because `row['y']` is a float and doesn't have the pandas methods.  `ddf['z'] = foo` is equivalent to `ddf = ddf.assign(z=foo)` for any `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience with dask but your boolean test will not catch that 2nd element as null in funcUpdate.  Null values with pandas are equal to None or NaN/Nan, not "".

```
def funcUpdate(row):
    try:
        return  round((1 + row['x'])/(1+ 1/row['y']),4)
    except:
        return row['y']
```

Is a possible workaround but you would need to run data validation before hand.

Comment: I think of one of the issues in my dataframe definition was that I defined Null as "" , where as it should be defined as "None"