# Creating a new dask dataframe column using values from another dataframe causes "chunk sizes are unknown" error

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to create a new column in a dask dataframe whose values will be specific index values from another dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
holdings=pd.DataFrame({'cusip': ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'], 'date': ['1/1/2000', '1/1/2005', '1/1/2010']})
ratings=pd.DataFrame({'cusip':['abcd','efgh','efgh'],'date':['1/1/2001','1/1/2004','1/1/2006'],'rating':['A','AAA','B']}
dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=2)
```

The dates are all datetime.date type. The goal is that for each row in holdings, the new column will contain the index from ratings where the row contains the most recently available rating for the cusip on the date in holdings. For example, the second row of the new column in holdings should contain the index that points to the second row of ratings.

I've written the following code that does what I'm looking for when holdings and ratings are just pandas data frames (not dask):

```
def get_rating_index(cusip,date,ratings):
    if cusip in ratings['cusip'].values:
        temp=ratings[ratings['cusip']==cusip]
        avail_ratings=temp[temp['date'].apply(lambda x: x<date)]
        if avail_ratings.shape[0]>0:
            final=avail_ratings[avail_ratings['date']==max(avail_ratings['date'].values)]
            return final.index[0]
        else:
            return np.nan
    else:
        return np.nan
holdings['ratings_match']=pd.Series(get_rating_index(holdings['cusip'][i],holdings['date'][i],ratings) for i in holdings.index)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212496/assign-add-a-new-column-to-a-dask-dataframe-based-on-values-of-2-existing-colu) was helpful for a simpler function that I needed to apply to this same data, but when I tried to use it for this task, I got the error: "Arrays chunk sizes are unknown: %s', (nan,), 'occurred at index 0".

This was the exact code I used with dask (slight modification from the function I was using with pandas):

```
def get_rating_index(row):
    if row['cusip'] in ratings['cusip'].values:
        temp=ratings[ratings['cusip']==row['cusip']]
        avail_ratings=temp[temp['date'].apply(lambda x: x<row['date'])]
        if avail_ratings.shape[0]>0:
            final=avail_ratings[avail_ratings['date']==max(avail_ratings['date'].values)]
            return final.index[0]
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return -1

holdings['ratings_match'] = holdings.apply(get_rating_index,meta='int', axis=1)
```

Any idea about how to do this without getting this error? I should note that the error occurs once when I try to see the data (eg. with `holdings.head()`), not immediately when I create the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer yet, but may get you started:

```
holdings.apply(get_rating_index, meta='int', axis=1)
```

It is *extremely likely* that you actually want `map` or `map_partition` here. They allow you to generalise from Pandas in a much more straight-forward way, and are usually much more efficient.

Indeed the function you are running, `get_rating_index` feels a lot like a single map or where operation, although it is hard to tell what the intent is. On the other hand, `temp=ratings[ratings['cusip']==row['cusip']]` looks like a groupby operation.

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that in addition to the simple grouping (```temp=ratings[ratings['cusip']==row['cusip']]```) I also need to ensure that the date from the ratings data frame occurs before the date from the holdings data frame (and then also ensure it is the most recent of the dates occuring before). If there is a simpler way to do this than my unnecessarily long function, that would be extremely helpful

Comment: I'm sure there is, pandas is magic. Dask dataframes make it hard to compare a row against all other rows, because they are not meant to be a single piece in memory at once by design.